# How do I thread a function?

Tags: c++, multithreading

A beginner's question, but how do I thread?

I have this code snippet:

```
std::vector<std::thread*> threads[8];
for (unsigned short rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < unimportantStuff.rows; ++rowIndex)
{
    for (unsigned short columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < unimportantStuff.columns; ++columnIndex)
    {
        myModelInstance = new CModelInstance;
        myModelInstance->Init(myLoader.CreateTriangle(myFramework.myDevice, { -0.8f + unimportantStuff.offset*columnIndex, -0.8f + unimportantStuff.offset*rowIndex }), { -0.8f + unimportantStuff.offset*columnIndex, -0.8f + unimportantStuff.offset*rowIndex });
        myScene.AddModelInstance(myModelInstance);
    }
}
```

I want to thread both the Init function and the AddModelInstance function if possible, however I don't know how to continue. How do I activate multiple threads (up to 8 in this case)?

I tried with a single thread like this:

```
std::thread t1(myScene.AddModelInstance, myModelInstance);
```

But I get the following error:

CScene::AddModelInstance': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

I tried adding & to both the function and the argument, but neither worked.

Comment: i bet you dont want an array of 8 vectors of pointers to threads. If you want a vector of threads, that would be `std::vector<std::thread>`

Comment: Why do you have a init function? Thats a code smell. Use the constructor, it is designed to initialize an object.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I don't know, it has crept into my code when I've seen my classmates codes. I think my teachers mentioned it is a code standard in the industry, but I see your point.

Comment: There are many problems here. You should use `std::vector<std::thread>>` and the constructor of `CModelInstance` (or a wrapper class) as already mentioned. You should also not use `new` unless you specifically want dynamic memory management. In that case, you should definitely use a smart pointer because any function that throws between `new` and the corresponding `delete` (which you forgot) will cause you to leak memory. In general, seek out a few tutorials on modern c++ and be weary of writing c-like code.

Comment: @patatahooligan Thanks, I will have another look at it next week.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of this:

```
std::thread t1(myScene.AddModelInstance, myModelInstance);
```

You need something like this:

```
std::thread t1(&Scene::AddModelInstance, myScene, myModelInstance);
```

`&Scene::AddModelInstance` is a pointer to the member function you want to call, which presumably takes an implicit `this` parameter (`myScene`).

Comment: It's not "presumably". Member functions have an implicit parameter that becomes `this` in the body

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I get the error: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments. What could that be?

Comment: @Caleth: It is "presumably" because the member function could be `static` in which case no `this`.  I guess not in OP's case though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `myScene` to be of type `Scene` try this:

```
std::thread t1(&Scene::AddModelInstance, &myScene, myModelInstance);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I get the error: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments. What could that be?

Comment: what is the signature of the function `AddModelInstance` ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what a signature is. The function returns a bool and it takes a CModelInstance pointer as an argument. Does this help? What it does is that is pushes the modelinstance into a vector then always returns true.

Comment: signature is what you explained, what is its input and output. if it gets a pointer as its input, is `myModelInstance` a pointer? if not try `&myModelInstance`

Comment: @NiklasUtterback can you post the declaration of `Scene::AddModelInstance`?

Comment: bool AddModelInstance(CModelInstance* aModelInstance);

Answer (score 0):

A clean and intuitive way is to use [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

```
std::thread t1([&]() mutable {myScene.AddModelInstance(myModelInstance);});
```

Do take note about capturing by reference or value

As a side note, make sure you have no [data races](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model) in your program

Comment: The application compiles now, but there are now random errors during runtime. I ran it four times and I got bad memory allocation error, nullptr error, vectour out of bounds and another bad memory allocation error. I guess there is some way to make it thread safe?